# Notebook not booting

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop

My problem is with my Samsung NP-N150 Notebook. It operates with a Windows 7 starter. I have never had any problems with it in the past.

The issue is that it will not boot up. The battery on my notebook has a great life, usually last around 7-8 hours. I recently tried to turn on my notebook and it seemed that the battery was dead.

I plugged in the adapter and the light associated with the adapter came on as orange. I tried to turning on the notebook and there was no response. I left it alone to charge, eventually the light became green, but there is still no response when I switch the power on.

When I unplug the adapter, the light goes off. My guess is that the battery is not retaining a charge, which is odd since the battery has never given me any problems. The other lights, such as the power and battery, do not turn on. The notebook is completely unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

Try to unplug the battery from the notebook and connect it directly to the adaptor.

Did your computer get exposed to an electric shock recently? Some computers lock the laptop to prevent the shock from damaging the hard disk.